# Any method for distinguishing which notification from the two in the status bar is clicked and started the main activity

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar, click

I have two Notifications code in the service of my app.

one  Notification is for message

```
 if (NOTIFICATION_COUNT_Message > 0){
                        Log.d("tag"," message notification start"); 
                        NotificationCompat.Builder mbuild = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                        mbuild.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.sms_on_click);
                        mbuild.setContentText(NOTIFICATION_COUNT_Message +" New Message");
                        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        PendingIntent resultIN = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),1234,in,0);
                        mbuild.setContentIntent(resultIN);
                        NotificationManager nmagr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        Notification notification=mbuild.build();
                        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                        nmagr.notify(1234,notification);
                        shr.edit().putString(MainActivity.KEY_ROOT_MESSAGE, "getMessage").commit();
                       // mbuild.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL   ;  

                     }
```

and second notifcation code is this

```
    if (NOTIFICATION_COUNT > 0){
                        Log.d("tag","notification start "); 
                        NotificationCompat.Builder mbuild = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                        mbuild.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.images1);
                        mbuild.setContentText(NOTIFICATION_COUNT +" New Message");
                        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        PendingIntent resultIN = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),code,in,0);
                        mbuild.setContentIntent(resultIN);
                        NotificationManager nmagr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        Notification notification=mbuild.build();
                        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                        nmagr.notify(code,notification);

                       // mbuild.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL   ;  
                        shr.edit().putString(MainActivity.KEY_ROOT_NOTIFY, "getAnecMessage").commit();
                     }
```

my problem is how can i work on the click event of these notification

in both the notification my main activity will be started as i have used

Intent in = new  Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP  );

### PendingIntent resultIN = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),code,in,0); mbuild.setContentIntent(resultIN);

.. problem arises is that it is unable to distinguish  wich notification started the activity so further code may get executed accordiing ..

so mainly i want to know is there any method that can identify the which notification started the main activity

i used common shared preference key.. but it gets override... so it is not the solution in any way..

a shared preference code used in both the notification with different key is also not helpfull as both the notification code works in parallel. so both keys will be updated.

shr.edit().putString(MainActivity.KEY_ROOT_NOTIFY, "getAnecMessage").commit();

shr.edit().putString(MainActivity.KEY_ROOT_MESSAGE, "getMessage").commit();

so i can just see one solution to my problem i.e an onclick method  for the two notifications on the status bar that can distinguish which notification accessed the main 
activity and separate code will be executed for the two different notification when clicked.

Comment: Your both Preferences value are different,right.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for my question :D .

i just tried it and it worked!!!

i used a common intent for both the notification declared globally in the service
and before passing the intent in the pending intent i assigned a string by using intent.putextra... nd now program is responding differently for both the notification

This is the first notification code :

```
 // in is intent declared globally in the service 
in = new intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP  );
 **in.putExtra("METHOD", "getAnecMessage");** // added this code
 PendingIntent resultIN = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),code,in,0);
```

this is the second notification code :

```
in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        in.putExtra("METHOD", "getMessage");
                        PendingIntent resultIN = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),1234,in,0);
```

is used same intent to pass 2 different values in a single key from two different notifications accordingly and then

now as i click on the notification it opens main and a bundle checks whether any intent started the main activity or not

if it is started by an intent for the notification from any part of the application 
the bundle checks for the code in main as :

```
  Bundle in = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(in!=null){
        str = in.getString("METHOD");
        if(str.equals("getMessage")==true){
            Log.d("tag Message","lanuch get message fragment");
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            getSlidingMenu().toggle();
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Messages");
            Messages msg=new Messages();
            ft.replace(R.id.details, msg);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.commit();
        }
        if(str.equals("getAnecMessage")==true){
             Log.d("tag Notification", "launch getanec message activity")   ;
                NotificationAdapter adapter=new NotificationAdapter(MainActivity.this, notification_data);
                if (adapter!=null) {
                list=(ListView)slidingMenu.findViewById(R.id.list_notification_menu);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);   
         }
        }
```

Hence Problem of distinguishing which notification started the main activity is solved :D!!!!
i hope this may help you too!!!